# Can I use TD Ameritrade API's for creating an app for commercial usage

Tags: api, ameritrade

I recently found out we are allowed to use TD's API if we have an account with them. However I am not entirely sure if we're allowed to use it to create our own applications that we want to sell on the market. I went to their site:  https://developer.tdameritrade.com/content/getting-started and it says `Each user is allowed to create only one app for private, non-commercial use. To inquire about commercial usage, please Contact Us.` I sent them an email but I havent recieved a reply from them. I tried calling and the guy at first said we're allowed to but he sounded uncertain and then told me to email these guys instead. I would think if we're trying to use their API for making money then they would probably want a commission fee or something.

Comment: Did you ever get a response from Ameritrade for this? I am also interested in their commercial version and sent them an email but never heard back. I am looking to see how to reach them about commercial use

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Legal questions, including questions about copyright or licensing, are off-topic [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, no. However, if the representative on the phone told you otherwise, I would take that and run with it. Personally, I would call again, ask for the representative's name, and see if you get the same answer. I might even suggest recording the conversation for your own records. If the representative tells you that using their API for commercial use is perfectly legal, it's likely that they wouldn't take any legal action; especially if you told them you were willing to pay the commission (or discontinue using their service). It may be hard to get their attention otherwise.

Comment: The API is limited to 120 calls per minute though, so trying to use a non-commercial account for a commercial app will scale to at most only a few users...